# Exclude div from Scrapy

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have this html:

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Title 1</h1><br><br>

    <h2>Sub-Title 1</h2>
    <br><br>
    Description 1.<br><br>Description 2.
    <br><br>

    <h2>Sub-Title 2</h2>
    <br><br>
    Description 1<br>Description 2<br>
    <br><br>

    <div class="infobox">
        <font style="color:#000000"><b>Information Title</b></font>
        <br><br>Long Information Text
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get all html in `<div id="content">` in Scrapy but excluding `<div class="infobox">`'s block, so the expected result is like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Title 1</h1><br><br>

    <h2>Sub-Title 1</h2>
    <br><br>
    Description 1.<br><br>Description 2.
    <br><br>

    <h2>Sub-Title 2</h2>
    <br><br>
    Description 1<br>Description 2<br>
    <br><br>
</div>
```

How can I modify my current selector:

```
item['article_html'] = hxs.select("//div[@id='content']").extract()[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this directly with selectors (xpath).

You could do something like this:

```
content = hxs.select("//div[@id='content']").extract()[0]
infobox = hxs.select("//div[@id='content']//div[@class='infobox']").extract()[0]

item['article_html'] = content.replace(infobox, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the element tree to remove the offending div:

```
>>> from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
>>> body = '''\
... <div id="content">
...     <h1>Title 1</h1><br><br>
... 
...     <h2>Sub-Title 1</h2>
...     <br><br>
...     Description 1.<br><br>Description 2.
...     <br><br>
... 
...     <h2>Sub-Title 2</h2>
...     <br><br>
...     Description 1<br>Description 2<br>
...     <br><br>
... 
...     <div class="infobox">
...         <font style="color:#000000"><b>Information Title</b></font>
...         <br><br>Long Information Text
...     </div>
... </div>
... '''
>>> resp = HtmlResponse(url='http://example.com', body=body, encoding='utf8')
>>> xhs = resp.selector
>>> infobox = xhs.css('.infobox')[0].root
>>> infobox.getparent().remove(infobox)
>>> print(xhs.select("//div[@id='content']").extract()[0])
<div id="content">
    <h1>Title 1</h1><br><br>

    <h2>Sub-Title 1</h2>
    <br><br>
    Description 1.<br><br>Description 2.
    <br><br>

    <h2>Sub-Title 2</h2>
    <br><br>
    Description 1<br>Description 2<br>
    <br><br>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the CSS selector `:not(...)` to exclude things.

Although **completely untested**, try something like this:

```
response.css("div[id='content']:not([class*='infobox'])")
```